# ¿Cómo modificar HTML y guardarlo en bases de datos?

Tags: php, html, dom

Tengo algunos archivos de texto que contienen HTML, lo que quiero hacer es modificar el código y guardarlo en una base de datos en local.

Todo el código sigue un mismo patrón, es una Tabla con Filas dentro, y dentro de estas codigo HTML, todo como dije sigue un mismo patrón.

Yo quiero reemplazar enlaces, eliminar elementos innecesarios, y guardar cada una de esas filas celdas de una tabla en una base de datos para luego recuperarlas.

Bueno lo edito a ver si se entiende:
Tengo código HTML, y quiero de alguna manera poder guardar partes por separado de este código, que tiene siempre la misma estructura, en una base de datos local (Wamserver).

Un ejemplo del codigo es asi:

```
<div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="mes"><td colspan="5">Enero</td></tr>
<tr class="dia-info">
........
</tr>
<tr class="datos">
<div class="div1">
........
</div>
<div class="div2">
........
</div>
</tr>
<tr class="dia-info">
........
</tr>
<tr class="datos">
<div class="div1">
........
</div>
<div class="div2">
........
</div>
</tr>
<tr class="dia-info">
........
</tr>
<tr class="datos">
<div class="div1">
........
</div>
<div class="div2">
........
</div>
</tr>
<tr class="mes"><td colspan="5">Febrero</td></tr>   
<tr class="dia-info">
........
</tr>
<tr class="datos">
<div class="div1">
........
</div>
<div class="div2">
........
</div>
</tr>  
</tbody>   
</table>   
</div>
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer es guardar en una base de datos cada uno de los datos:

```
<tr class="dia-info">
........
</tr>
<tr class="datos">
<div class="div1">
........
</div>
<div class="div2">
........
</div>
</tr>
```

por separado, pero antes tengo que reemplazar algunas cosas es cada uno de estos PARES DE FILAS de esta tabla Html, por ejemplo reemplazar cadenas de texto, eliminar algunos elementos innecesario, etc.

Lo que yo quiero saber es, como me recomiendan hacer este tipo de tarea, si con PHP solo se puede o hay que usar SI o SI Javascript para trabajar con el DOM.

Lo que no quiero es enrollarme con algo que quizás sea mas fácil de lo que yo creo, por eso pregunto a gente que seguro sabe muchísimo, yo estoy aprendiendo.

Lo que a mi me gustaría poder hacer es un .html o .php donde yo pegue el código este que hay que ordenar, toque un botón y cada uno de los datos de guarde en X tabla de una base de datos.

Las funciones para reemplazar enlaces, eliminar elementos, etc, después veré en que lenguaje las hago, dependiendo de que me respondan.

Comment: Si buscas recomendaciones, esta pregunta se basaría en opiniones y no entraría bien dentro del formato del sitio. Si lo que buscas es cómo hacerlo, esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y deberías añadir más información (¿qué has intentado?¿con qué problemas te estás encontrando?). Por favor, lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para más información y consejos.

Comment: Si, busco como hacerlo, como guardo partes de codigo HTML dentro de una base de datos, antes cambiando parte del codigo?    se puede hacer solo con PHP?

Comment: Mira esta pagina http://jsbeautifier.org/, bueno yo quisiera tener algo en local, poder pegar código HTML y guardar ciertos elementos de este codigo en una base de datos, pero antes reemplazar atributos de estos elementos y también eliminar algunos que no me sirve.

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es un parseador de HTML, lo cual sería demasiado amplio para el formato de Stack Overflow. Incluso limitando sólo al HTML de los datos, limpiar ese código puede ser difícil y costoso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo analizar HTML usando la extensión [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php). Lleva bastante familiarizarse con cada uno de los métodos, para poder hacer cada una de las modificaciones que quieras, pero es relativamente fácil buscar cómo hacer cada operación. Al fin y al cabo, termina siendo un método idéntico a como lo manipularías en JavaScript.

El primer paso es generar el documento:

```
//Teniendo el HTML como texto...
$html = '<div><table><tbody><tr><td>Enero</td></tr><tr><td>Etc...</td></tr></tbody></table></div>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$libxml_opciones = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_NOERROR;
@$dom->loadHTML($html, $libxml_opciones);
```

Y, a partir de ahí, nos manejamos con el documento (`$dom`) para seleccionar cada fila:

```
//Obtenemos todas las tablas en el doc
$tablas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
//Recorremos c/u
foreach ($tablas as $tabla) {
    //Obtenemos cada <tr>
    $trs = $tabla->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    $fila_nro = 0;
    //Recorremos c/u
    foreach ($trs as $tr) {


        // Y acá podemos manipular cada <tr>, haciendo lo que quieras hacer sobre $tr

        // Luego, obtenemos el HTML de este elemento como texto:
        $html_fila = $dom->saveHTML($tr);

        //podemos imprimir el HTML de la fila para depurar lo que hicimos
        echo ('HTML Fila: ' . ++$fila_nro . "\n$html_fila\n\n");


    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4dOXh

---

Estas son algunas de las operaciones que mencionaste, con código simplificado (sin validar nada):

- Reemplazar cadenas de texto:

  Supongamos que tenés un `<tr><td>Texto</td></tr>`:

  ```
  $primer_td = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
  $primer_td->nodeValue = 'Nuevo texto';
  ```
- Reemplazar enlaces

  Teniendo `<tr><td><a href="url"></a></td></tr>`:

  ```
  $primer_a = $tr->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
  $primer_a->setAttribute('href','https://es.stackoverflow.com');
  ```
- Eliminar elementos

  Con `<tr><eliminar></eliminar></tr>`:

  ```
  $tr->removeChild( $tr->firstChild );
  ```

Todos los métodos están en http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php. Y seguramente te sería fácil encontrar buscando en la web cómo hacer cada modificación. Si no, podés hacer una nueva pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: Hola @Mariano, es lo que quería saber gracias!

Comment: A esa variable "$html" la podría tomar desde un texarea donde yo pegue el código no? Y también podría desde  el mismo documento guardarlo en una base de datos?

Comment: @DanielMartinez Claro! Es un string, no importa de dónde viene, sólo es texto. Si es HTML válido o no, ya es otro tema (dispararía un error al crear el DOM), pero si válido se genera el `DOMDocument` con estructura de árbol y clases propias (`DOMNode`/`DOMElement` principalmente). Esa estructura y esas clases son las que te permiten analizar HTML correctamente (sabrás que tratar de buscar o reemplazar con métodos de strings/regex es un gran error), esta es la forma. Hay otras extensiones que hacen lo mismo (SimpleXML, XML Parser, etc.), pero DOM es la básica y un buen lugar para empezar.

Comment: Bueno @Mariano, me sacaste muchas dudas, justamente tenia las dudas que mencionas, estaba buscando y vi que hacer este tipo de tareas con expresiones regulares era un error, y no sabía bien cual era la manera optima de hacerlo, sabia de las otras extensiones pero bueno intentare con DOM, muchas gracias!